# Run maven using a different version of Java than the one used to run maven

Tags: java, maven, java-home, maven-enforcer-plugin

I'm using maven 3.2.5 to build my project, this version of maven is compatible with java 6.

I want to build a project that enforces using java 5 with maven-enforcer-plugin.

If I set JAVA_HOME to java 5 directory, I can't run maven and if I set JAVA_HOME to java 6 directory, the enforcer plugin complains about java version.

Is there a way to to tell maven to use a different version of java from the one that is used to run maven?

Comment: Why do you want to build with java 5?????

Comment: It's an old code that I have received from a co-worker and he forced it in pom file!

Comment: You probably should (I would) use an up to date java compiler on this project. And if *for some reason* you really need to run it with java 5 then [enforce the language level to 1.5](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html)

Comment: @RC In some situations it's really needed to use the correct JDK apart from that language level via source/target is not enogh.

Comment: @khmarbaise (out of curiosity) any example?

Comment: I have a simple example. If your language level is 1.5 but your JDK 1.6. Than you can use thing like `String.isEmpty()` but the problem is that `isEmpty()` is available from JDK 6 and not from 1.5 and the source/taget will not prevent that. This can be prevented if you use things like [animal-sniffer-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/animal-sniffer/animal-sniffer-maven-plugin/) as well.

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is situation where you need to use toolchains which can exactly solve the problem. Like running Maven with JDK 7 (for example Maven 3.5.0) but the code needs to be compiled and tested with JDK 6.

See the documentation about [toolchains](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use maven compiler plugin to setup which javac do you want to use, for example:

```
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <verbose>true</verbose>
      <fork>true</fork>
      <executable>WRITE HERE THE PATH TO YOUR JAVAC 1.5</executable>
      <compilerVersion>1.5</compilerVersion>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: This will not work correctly. cause the bootclasspath is not correctly set in such situations. With this setup it will be possible to use JDK 6 methods (for example String.isEmpty()) but if you run on JRE 5 this will fail...Only correct way to handle this is using toolchains...Apart from that using javac is one thing but what about running the tests on which JRE/JDK ?

Answer (score -1):

Right click on project

- Click properties
- Click on project Facets
- Select java version
- Click on Apply

Comment: This will not help. This will not change a thing in Maven. If you use Maven the only truth is in Maven and not in Ecipse anymore...